# mypy doesn't complain when class doesn't implement protocol

Tags: python, interface, mypy, typing

I have the following code. Class `A` contains a function `f`. Class `B` inherits from `A` and overrides this function. I also have protocol `SupportsG` which acts as a structural supertype to all classes implementing a function `g`. I have class `B` explicitly inherit this protocol:

```
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsG(Protocol):
  def g(self) -> str: ...

class A:
  def f(self) -> str:
    return ""

class B(A, SupportsG):
  def f(self) -> str:
    return "test"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  b = B()
```

My expectation here is that `mypy` would throw an error, because class `B` doesn't implement function `g`. However, if I run `mypy --strict` I get no errors.

What is the gap in my understanding here?

Comment: Happens to me as well - I defined a protocol with 3 methods, then a class that should implement it that has just "pass" without implementing the protocol. Pylance tells me I'm not implementing the protocol, but no errors from mypy

Comment: `class B(A, SupportsG)` means that `B` is a new protocol (with g and f). It does **not** means that `B` should be compatible with the protocol. That's the point of structural inheritance: you **don't** *name* the base class.

Comment: @Wombatz `B` is not a Protocol, is a standard class with `g` and `f`. To be a Protocol, the Protocol must always appear in the base classes.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def test(x: SupportsG):
  pass  # whatever

a = A()
b = B()

test(a)  # mypy should complain
test(b)  # mypy should complain

class C:
  def g(self) -> str:
    return ""

c = C()
test(c)  # should be fine
```

You don't need to inherit your class from `SupportsG`.

Btw, one purpose for `Protocol` is also to define custom function interfaces with kwargs, which is not possible with `Callable`, like:

```py
def func(a, *, b) -> str:
  pass

class Func(Protocol):
  def __call__(self, a, *, b) -> str: ...

def test(f: Func):
  pass

test(func)  # ok!
```

Answer (score 0):

`Protocol` is for use in structural typing to define input types, not in inheritance.

You should be using [`ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) instead of `Protocol`; it does exactly what you want.